# How to include header files from WSL Linux distributive in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am going to compile the program for Linux in Ms Visual Studio 2019 using WSL_1_0 Toolset (new feature added in May in addition to remote connection). Everything is OK if I compile a simple program like "Hello, World!", but when I added some additional header files into the program such as `#include<deal.II/grid/tria.h>` VS 2019 cannot find these files. The requiered header files are installed in my WSL Linux distributives.

So the question is: how to include in my Windows VS project header files from my Linux distributive? I followed this instructions

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-with-visual-studio-2019-and-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/

but wasn't able to figure out how to copy these files into my project properly.

Comment: Unless `deal.II` is in `/usr/include`, it should be added as an "additional include path". That's as much as I can say given the little information you provided.

Comment: @rustyx thanks for your comment. `Deal.ii` is installed in `/usr/include`. So all the header files from this directory should be seen by VS?

Comment: I think that if they are headers in your project they should be imported using "" instead of <>. Have you tested in Windows without WSL? Just to test that it is not a problem of WSL integration